# jquery.dataTables.min.js:94 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4

Am using jquery ajax bootstrap dataTables,when am trying to download morethan 20k records getting this error in console log" Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded jquery.dataTables.min.js:94".Upto 2k records able to download as csv and Excel format. I was tried all stackoverflow solutions with same issue.But not used any solution. Below is my code php codeigniter framework used.

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({ 
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                //'pdfHtml5',
                'pageLength'
            ],
            "pageLength": 25,
            "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
            "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
            "order": [], //Initial no order.
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0]}],
            "bInfo": false, //niranjan kumar chowdam added for remove pagination numbers 
            lengthMenu: [
                [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
                [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
            ],
            // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
            "ajax": {
                "url": "http://100.250.90.110:8090/srx/voucher/credit_vouchers_datatable",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function ( data ) {
                    
                    data.FromDate   = $('#FromDate').val();
                    data.ToDate     = $('#ToDate').val(); 
                }
            },
    
            //Set column definition initialisation properties.
            
        });
```

Comment: 20,000 records is ***far too many*** to display on the client side, and will lead to performance problems - as you've discovered. If you have that much data you will need to implement server side paging/filtering/searching on the datatable

Comment: Is this when trying to display on the datatable?  Or only when you attempt download to xlsx / csv?

Comment: Server side ajax using for display records , but unable to download all records from table upto 20k records.

Comment: @freedomn-m this issue only attempt to download xlsx/csv or any format upto 20k records , displaying is fine working but download not working.

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or an AJAX problem?